# C programming, char array memory allocation issue

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm developing a small C library to teach videogames programming and I created one simple function to draw formatted text on screen (i.e. score, lives). The function is:

```
const char *FormatText(const char *text, ...)
{
    int length = strlen(text);
    char *buffer = malloc(length + 20);

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, text);
    vsprintf(buffer, text, args);
    va_end(args);

    return buffer;
}
```

This function is used in the main game loop, in the Draw section, as follow:

```
DrawText(FormatText("%02i", score), 10, 10, 40, BLACK);
```

The extra parameters in DrawText() func, just represent screen coordinates X, Y, font size and color.

I'm calling this function about 60 times per second (or even more), so, if I'm right, I'm allocating new memory every call... and I'm never freeing that memory!

How could I solve this issue to keep using my function the same way?

My first thought was creating a global char *buffer on my library, allocate it at initialization and reuse it all the time... but I'm not sure if that's the best idea, I try to avoid too many globals.

Thanks very much for your answers!

### UPDATE

Again, thanks to you all for your answers.

Finally the way I solved this issue was using:

```
const char *FormatText(const char *text, ...)
{
    static char buffer[MAX_FORMATTEXT_LENGTH];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, text);
    vsprintf(buffer, text, args);
    va_end(args);

    return buffer;
}
```

Probably is not the best solution but I think it's the best for the user of the lib, not having to worry about memory management.

Here it is a simple usage example:

```
#include "raylib.h"

int main()
{
    int score = 100020;
    int hiscore = 200450;
    int lives = 5;

    InitWindow(800, 450, "testing FormatText()");

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose())    // Detect window close button or ESC key
    {
        BeginDrawing();

            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);

            DrawText(FormatText("Score: %08i", score), 80, 80, 20, RED);
            DrawText(FormatText("HiScore: %08i", hiscore), 80, 120, 20, GREEN);
            DrawText(FormatText("Lives: %02i", lives), 80, 160, 40, BLUE);
            DrawText(FormatText("Elapsed Time: %02.02f ms", GetFrameTime()*1000), 80, 220, 20, BLACK);

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

That's the result:

[image: testing FormatText() raylib function]

Comment: You could allocate the buffer just before the call to `FormatText` (since you know the value of `strlen(text)` even before entering the function), and free the memory right after.

Comment: Ray, does `DrawText` have a return value? Or better, could you just provide the `DrawText`?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin You can see DrawText() implementation here: [link] https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/text.c [/link]

Comment: @Ray What do you mean by *keep using my function the same way*? I mean, you could, for example, simply add a `free( text )` at the end of `DrawText` function...

Comment: @ThoAppelsin I would like that when using DrawText(), user doesn't need to worry about allocation and free. Adding free(text) at the end of DrawText() it's a good solution but then I can not use the const qualifier for char *text.

Comment: @Ray: Then consider using Boehm GC as I told in my answer. Your users won't worry about freeing.

Comment: @Ray Why really? You can `free` the allocated memory of constant characters, provided that the memory allocated is allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, etc.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin You're right, I can cast the const char *text on free to (void *) and it works but after considering that solution it doesn't convince me, if FormatText() is not used with DrawText(), I have the same problem... I think I'll use a global variable, initialing it at Window creating and freeing it at closing...

Answer (score 1):

I'd pass the responsibility to manage memory to the parent function. It would allocate and free as needed, rather than `FormatText()` itself

```
// somefunction
    char *buffer;
    buffer = malloc(<somesize>);
    if (buffer) {
        FormatText(buffer, "%02i", ...);
        free(buffer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function nearly already exist in some Libc, like the [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/), it is called [asprintf(3)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html). The caller is expected to `free` the `malloc`-ed buffer.

You could use it as:

```
char* msg=NULL;
DrawText((msg=FormatText("%02i", score)), 10, 10, 40, BLACK);
free (msg);
```

or, if using `asprintf`, using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator),

```
char* msg=NULL;
DrawText((asprintf(&msg,"%02i",score),msg), 10, 10, 40, BLACK);
free (msg);
```

At last, if you are bothered by calling `free` as you should, you could decide that your entire program uses the [Boehm garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) (so you'll call `GC_MALLOC` and don't bother to `GC_FREE`). Then you would define

```
char* GC_sprintf(const char*fmt, ...) {
   char buf[128];
   va_list ap;
   va_start (ap, fmt);
   int sz = vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, ap);
   va_end (ap);
   if (sz < sizeof(buf)) return GC_strdup (buf);
   char* gcbuf = GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC (sz+1);
   memset (gcbuf, 0, sizeof (gcbuf));
   va_start (ap, fmt);
   vsnprintf(gcbuf, sz, fmt, ap);
   va_end (ap);
   return gcbuf;
}
```

and simply call

```
DrawText(GC_sprintf("%02i",score), 10, 10, 40, BLACK);
```

BTW, since `"%02i"` format produces a short string, you could use

```
char locbuf[8];
snprintf (locbuf, sizeof(locbuf), "%02i", score);
DrawText(locbuf, 10, 10, 40, BLACK);
```

and you could even consider defining your variadic `DrawText_printf` and call

```
DrawText_printf(10, 10, 40, BLACK, "%02i", score);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Reading it I got the idea to just define the buffer inside FormatText() as: static char buffer[MAX_FORMATTEX_LENGHT]; I'm considering that option...

Comment: That won't work if several calls to `FormatText` occur in a single statement.

Comment: It's true but that's not the intended way for that function to be used. The typical way this function will be used is: DrawText(FormatText("Score: %08i", score), 80, 80, 20, RED); DrawText(FormatText("Lives: %08i", lives), 80, 160, 40, BLUE); DrawText(FormatText("Elapsed Time: %02.02f ms", GetFrameTime()*1000), 80, 220, 20, BLACK);